# How to hide a window in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have two views bound to the same view model. In the main window view model class, a second window is created and opened. How to hide the second window when its button is clicked? A hide() command does not work when bound to a button in the second view, but the window is hidden if the same command is bound to a button in the main window.

How to hide the second window?
Function in MainWindowViewModel:

```
public void DeclineSettingsChanges()
{
    SW.Hide();
}
```

Reactive command:

```
private ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> DeclineSettingsChangesCommand { get; }
```

Creting command in constructor:

```
DeclineSettingsChangesCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(DeclineSettingsChanges);
```

SettingsWindow.axaml part:

```
<Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding DeclineSettingsChanges, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}"/>
```

Similarly, the binded button in MainWindow.axaml works as it should and hides the SettingsWindows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create 2 view models?

Answer (score 0):

Windows are closed using the `Close()` method, personally, I've never used the `Hide()` method on a `Window` so not entirely sure of it's internal workings.

You may find it helpful to use a library for dialogs and Windows. I've written a small simple library that you can get here:

https://github.com/jamsoft/JamSoft.AvaloniaUI.Dialogs